# Javascript Object-MapAreas

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to create map areas in objects on a separated js file ? How does the html know that this is an map area ?

This works in html

html:

```
<map name="navigation">
<area shape="rect" coords="18,131,113,140" href="Homepage.html" alt="Homepage">
    ......
```

But how does it work in js ?

js:

```
 var links= new Area("area1", "area2", "area3");
    area1[0]= [45, 143, 106, 158] ;
    area2.... does this work ?
    var screenX1 = {
        image:"image001.png", 
        links: [
            {
                area1:[45, 143, 106, 158];
                ???
            }
.....
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? Do you try to create areas from your JS file ?

Comment: Yes and I'm not sure how to do it correctly ^^

Comment: you can use http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_area.asp or you can use jquery (which makes it more easy to deal with dom elements)

Comment: Ok thank you. I don't know jquery that well though it's the same as JavaScript xD

Comment: Is it possible to source the picture for the map in js and not in the html file ?

Comment: I think it's not usefull to use DOM Area for me because I want to have one html file and one js file with all map area coords and pictures source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but you should have a look on http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_area.asp . The idea is to have an array where you store different info about the areas. Then you loop through this array to create your domElements. Something like that :

```js
// Remember the id of the image to display
var _currentImageId = 'earth';

// Get DOM elements
var _map = document.getElementById('myMap'),
    _image = document.getElementById('myImage');

// Describe images and maps related
var _images = {
  earth : {
    path: 'earth.png',
    areas: [
      { 
        coords: '45, 12, 50, 10',
        goto: 'europe'
      },
      { 
        coords: '20, 63, 54, 21',
        goto: 'america'
      }//etc
    ]
  },
  europe: {
    path: 'europe.png',
    areas: [
      { 
        coords: '50, 63, 14, 10',
        goto: 'france'
      }//etc
    ]
  },
}

function refreshImage(){
  // Get the image
  var image = _images[_currentImageId];
  
  // Update the image source
  _image.src = image.path;
  
  // Update the map
  _map.innerHTML = ""; //empty the map
  image.areas.forEach(function(area){
    // Create the area element to append to the DOM
    var areaElem = document.createElement('AREA');
  
    // Set attributes
    areaElem.coords = area.coords
    areaElem.setAttribute('link', area.goto);
    
    // Add click listener on areas
    areaElem.addEventListener('click', onArea_click)
    
    _map.appendChild(areaElem);
  })
}

function onArea_click(domEvent){
  // Update current image id
  _currentImageId = domEvent.target.getAttribute('link');
  
  // Refresh the view
  refreshImage();
}
```

```html
<img id="myImage"/>

<map name="navigation" id="myMap"></map>
```

Hope it helps... ;)

**Edit**
Below is a working example :

```js
// Remember the id of the image to display
var _currentImageId = 'homepage';

// Get DOM elements
var _map = document.getElementById('myMap'),
  _image = document.getElementById('myImage');

// Describe images and maps related
var _images = {
  homepage: {
    path: 'https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/218125/3d-Earth-Globe.png',
    areas: [{
        //  type:'rect',
        coords: '0,0,200,200',
        text: 'Homepage',
        goto: 'homepage'
      }, {
        // type:'rect',
        coords: '300,0,500,500',
        text: 'Editable',
        goto: 'editable'
      }, {
        coords: '45,164,149,180',
        text: 'Search',
        goto: 'search'
      }, {
        coords: '45,181,108,196',
        text: 'Set Free',
        goto: 'setfree'
      }
    ]
  },
  editable: {
    path: 'http://highmars.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/high-mars-10.jpg',
    areas: [{
        coords: '676,1901,1240',
        goto: 'order'
      } //etc
    ]
  }
}

refreshImage();

function refreshImage() {
  // Get the image
  var image = _images[_currentImageId];

  // Update the image source
  _image.src = image.path;

  // Update the map
  _map.innerHTML = ""; //empty the map
  image.areas.forEach(function(area) {
    // Create the area element to append to the DOM
    var areaElem = document.createElement('AREA');

    // Set attributes
    areaElem.coords = area.coords;
    areaElem.setAttribute('link', area.goto);
    areaElem.setAttribute("title", area.text);
    areaElem.setAttribute("shape", "rect");

    // Add click listener on areas
    areaElem.addEventListener('click', onArea_click);

    _map.appendChild(areaElem);
  })
}

function onArea_click(domEvent) {
  // Update current image id
  _currentImageId = domEvent.target.getAttribute('link');

  // Refresh the view
  refreshImage();
}
```

```css
#myImage{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>logo</td>
    <td>description</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <img id="myImage" usemap="#navigation"/>
      <map name="navigation" id="myMap"> </map>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How can I call a different area when one area is clicked in JavaScript and it should also show the new picture with the new area map ?

Comment: You can just add a href property in your area objects. Then set the href property in the loop : areaElem.href = area.href.

Comment: Do you want to navigate to an other url when you click an area ? Or you want to dynamically change the image and the map associated to this image?

Comment: I want to change the image and the right area map is associated ^^

Comment: I updated my answer. Basically I added a click listener on areas to refresh the DOM... Try to use that with your images. I did not test it but it should work

Comment: Hmm can't click on Areas. I used  areaElem.setAttribute("shape", "rect"); Still not working =( Or can I even write in obejcts  type:"rect" , ?

Comment: Yes you can add a type property in the objects. You may need to add href='#' to be able to click on the area I dont know...

Comment: Where should I add the href tags ? And why do I need href tags ? I only have one html file .... ^^ Nevertheless thank you for you work ^-^

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle with some images ? Then I'll try to help you correcting your code it will be easier ;)

Comment: What do you mean with fiddle? ^^

Comment: You can you https://jsfiddle.net/ to set up a basic sample of your code. You can also do it directly by editing your First question and using built-in stackoverflow's sample code (like I did to write snippets)

Comment: ok, thats what I have. Where can I add pictures ? https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=zUnlIr9c7n

Comment: Doesn't work. Example:  https://www.google.at/search?hl=de&authuser=0&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1920&bih=979&q=earth&oq=earth&gs_l=img.3..0l10.657.1178.0.1337.5.4.0.1.1.0.115.169.3j1.4.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..0.5.166.WrNZSMObVSw#imgrc=1PFB-aQYPKgMuM%3A

Comment: Right click and open the image in a new tab. Then use the tab's url (for example https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/218125/3d-Earth-Globe.png)

Comment: Ok now I have the pictures, but I still can't click on the area ^^  https://jsfiddle.net/uvpmup1q/2/

Comment: I corrected your jsfiddle and edited my answer! Have a look on what I did, it's working. Tell me if you need explanation ;)

Comment: Can you post the link ? ^^ Ok i saw it ^^  I will test it with my pictures now. Thank you for you work . You helped me alot =) When I have problems I will notify you =)

Comment: No problem ;) Good luck !

Comment: How can I use static map areas ? I want to use the homepage area for many other areas, I can do it, but then the code will get soo long. How to use it for every area calling the area so the code gets shorter  ? https://jsfiddle.net/nyxg8s53/1/

Comment: Something in this direction, doesn`t seem to work though ^^  https://jsfiddle.net/ruyqs53u/

Comment: Or do I have to create a new object with the area homepage and then I can call it from _images  for any areas. ?

Comment: Hmm Need your help ^^ How can I add a function into a area within the object? Also how can I declare from the function to an object key I mean to the area?  https://jsfiddle.net/3sqe6otf/2/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question... However you should create a new question on Stackoverflow you will have an answer straight away ;) For what I understand regarding your jsfiddle, you want to execute a function when clicking the area... Your code seems to be good... just dont forget to add the onclick property when you create the DOM element.

Comment: If I'm right you want to know which area has been clicked inside the function ? To do that, have a look on JS events (e.g http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html). When the click handler is called, there is a parameter e (the name does not matter...) which represents the event. You can then access the clicked element (the area in your case) checking e.target ;) Hope it helps ;)

Comment: I made a new question. Hope you will answer =)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38499441/how-to-execute-a-function-when-clicking-an-area-inside-an-object