# How to execute a function when clicking an area inside an object?

Tags: javascript

I created an object with map Areas by using DOM-Elements. Now I want to execute a function when clicked on an area(coordinates). I think I also Need to check the area if it is clicked or not ?  Also I think I'm missing something on the DOM-Element.

```
var _images = { //Object-MapArea
    start: {
      path: 'start.jpg',
      areas: [{
        coords: '18,131,113,140',
        text: 'Homepage',
        onclick: doSomething, // ??? 

      }]
    },

  }
  // ..... there is more code not shown here
  //Creating DOM-Elements
var areaElem = document.createElement('AREA');

// Set attributes
areaElem.coords = area.coords;
areaElem.setAttribute('link', area.goto);
areaElem.setAttribute("title", area.text);
areaElem.setAttribute("shape", "rect");
areaElem.onclick = doSomething; ? ? ?
if (element.captureEvents) element.captureEvents(Event.CLICK); ? ? ?
areaElem.addEventListener('click', onArea_click);
_map.appendChild(areaElem);
function doSomething(e) {
  if (!e) var e = window.event
  e.target = ... ? ?



    var r = confirm("Data will get lost!");
  if (r == true) {
    window.open("homepage.html", "_parent");
  } else {
    window.open(" ", "_parent"); // here I want to stay in the current pictures. I mean the current object map area. But how can I refer to it so it stays there ?  
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the comments I added to your code ;)

```js
var _images = { //Object-MapArea
  start: {
    path: 'start.jpg',
    areas: [{
      coords: '18,131,113,140',
      text: 'Homepage',
      clickHandler: doSomething // I changed the name to avoid confusion but you can keep onclick 
    }]
  },
}

// ..... there is more code not shown here
//Creating DOM-Elements
var areaElem = document.createElement('AREA');

// Set attributes
areaElem.coords = area.coords;
areaElem.setAttribute('link', area.goto);
areaElem.setAttribute("title", area.text);
areaElem.setAttribute("shape", "rect");

// Add a listener on click event (using the function you defined in the area object above)
areaElem.addEventListener('click', area.clickHandler);

// Add your other click handler
areaElem.addEventListener('click', onArea_click);

_map.appendChild(areaElem);


function doSomething(e) {
  // Get the area clicked
  var areaClicked = e.target;

  // I dont understand the following code...
  var r = confirm("Data will get lost!");
  if (r == true) {
    window.open("homepage.html", "_parent");
  } else {
    window.open(" ", "_parent"); // here I want to stay in the current pictures. I mean the current object map area. But how can I refer to it so it stays there ?  
  }

}
```

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Thank you. You are my hero =) When you click on this area it should pop up a window with the message in confirm. When you press Yes you will redirected to an area like Example goto: 'asdf' So you should get forward to asdf and No to another area(Picture)

Comment: ok so just after getting the areaClicked, get the link attribute of the element (like it's done in the onArea_click function)

Comment: Furthermore I have another question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501885/how-can-i-use-object-properties-for-other-object-values-inside-the-same-object

Comment: Do I need something like that . _images.edit.areas=_images.homepage.areas ? To use the same areas for another area map ? So the code gets shorter.

Answer (score 0):

> I think I also Need to check the area if it is clicked or not

You are creating an element `areaElem` and attaching event to the same dom. 
So there may not be need of any more check

You may not need to add both `onclick` & `addEventListner` on same element and for same event. Either `onclick` function or `addEventListener` will be sufficient to handle the event.

```
areaElem.onclick = function(event){
// Rest of the code
// put an alert to validate if this function is responding onclick

}


areaElem.addEventListener('click', onArea_click);
function onArea_click(){
// Rest of the code

}
```

Comment: Don`t I have do declare doSomething somewhere?

Comment: what you want to declare?

Comment: onclick: doSomething (function), it's in the object above.

Comment: No onclick is an event handler. So I think it will work

Comment: areaElem.onclick =  function (event){

 alert("Hallo");
}        To test it ?